# In a stacked bar chart, how do I find which bar I have clicked on?

Tags: vb.net, teechart

At the moment I have a form with a tChart control called tChart:..

```
Private Sub txtChart1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtChart1.Click


TChart1.Series.Clear()

Dim series1 As New Steema.TeeChart.Chart

Dim FirstLabel = New Label()
FirstLabel.Name = "FirstLabel.Name"
FirstLabel.Text = " FirstLabel.Text"

Dim SecondLabel = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
Dim GridBand = New Steema.TeeChart.Tools.GridBand()

'Main bar 1
Dim BarSeries1 = New Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar()
BarSeries1.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(192, 255, 48)
BarSeries1.MultiBar = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.Stacked
BarSeries1.Pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(48, 255, 192)
BarSeries1.Title = "barSeries1"
BarSeries1.XValues.DataMember = "X"
BarSeries1.XValues.Order = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ValueListOrder.Ascending
BarSeries1.YValues.DataMember = "Bar"

BarSeries1.Add({123, 123, 123, 123, 123})

TChart1.Series.Add(BarSeries1)


'Main bar 2
Dim BarSeries2 = New Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar()
BarSeries2.Brush.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(48, 255, 192)
BarSeries2.MultiBar = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.MultiBars.Stacked
BarSeries2.Pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(48, 255, 192)
BarSeries2.Title = "barSeries2"
BarSeries2.XValues.DataMember = "X"
BarSeries2.XValues.Order = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ValueListOrder.Ascending
BarSeries2.YValues.DataMember = "Bar"

BarSeries2.Add({123, 123, 123, 123, 123})

TChart1.Series.Add(BarSeries2)


TChart1.Aspect.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality


End Sub
```

...in the same form class I have this event handler...

```
Private Sub TChart1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TChart1.MouseDown
mouseX.Text = e.X
mouseY.Text = e.Y

If TChart1.Series.Count > 0 Then

Dim CollectionOfBars As New List(Of String)

For idxSeries As Integer = 0 To TChart1.Series.Count - 1
Dim srs As Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar = TChart1.Series(idxSeries)

If srs.BarBounds.Contains(e.X, e.Y) Then
CollectionOfBars.Add(srs.TitleOrName)
End If

Next

txtCollisions.Text = Join(CollectionOfBars.ToArray, ", ")
End If

End Sub
```

...but what it does is only work for the last stack of bars. I need something that will work for all bars.

Please help.

Comment: Check out the following... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316319/finding-series-item-clicked-in-a-chart-in-vb-2008/11317283#11317283

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub tctChartBar_Click(Sender As Object, srsBarSeriesClicked As Styles.Series, ValueIndex As Integer, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles tctScrollableChart.ClickSeries
    Dim strMethodAddress As String = strClassAddress & "Private Sub Bar_Click(Sender As Object, srsBarSeriesClicked As Styles.Series, ValueIndex As Integer, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles GetChartComponent.ClickSeries"
    Try
        Dim CAAGCanvasConversionBreakdownCriteria As clsCriteria = ctaCriteriaSetting.Copy
        CAAGCanvasConversionBreakdownCriteria.SetWeekNum(srsBarSeriesClicked(ValueIndex).Label)
        frmCAAGCanvasConversionBreakdown.RemoteLaunch(CAAGCanvasConversionBreakdownCriteria, GetSelectedCanvassGroupID)

    Catch ex As Exception
        If blnLoudExceptions Then MsgBox("General Exception Caught in Method: " & strMethodAddress)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Clicked method:

```
If srs.Clicked(e.X, e.Y) <> -1 Then
CollectionOfBars.Add(srs.TitleOrName)
End If
```

instead of the code you use:

```
If srs.BarBounds.Contains(e.X, e.Y) Then
CollectionOfBars.Add(srs.TitleOrName)
End If
```

It may also be more suitable using the ClickSeries event to do the job. If this doesn't help don't hesitate to let me know.